# How to put raw HTML form <textarea> tag in WordPress Code Block/Text Block

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, textarea, codeblocks

I am trying to use below code in the WordPress Code Block or Text Block. But by adding , it removes the entire code from the Code Block and showing form outside in the WordPress editor screen with lot of junk characters.

```html
<style>
 .leftCol
{
  width: 47%;
}

.rightCol
{
 width: 47%;
float: right;

}

</style>

<form action="../process.php" method="post" name="myForm">

<div class="rightCol">
Name <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
Phone <input id="" type="number" name="phone" />
</div>

<div class="leftCol">
Email <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
Company <input id="comp" type="text" name="comp" />
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

How can I use this line of code

```html
 <textarea width='100'></textarea>
```

within the form code.Please share an example.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create a specific template for the page you need to insert the form. With it you can control the look and the structure without having wp filters stripping your tags..

add `page-yourSlug.php` to your current theme. Copy code from `page.php` and customize accordingly. yourSlug is the id or name of the page you creating.

Comment: Thanks @funkysoulzh for sharing the alternative. I need to use Pardot form handler with this  form where I will put the handler code in the action value of the form. Is that achievable through your method?